# Viewing website in a webview brings up webpage not available

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, webview

Hey all first Android project here...

I found this code for loading a website inside a webview:

```
package com.example.mainactivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mWebView = new WebView(this);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        this.setContentView(mWebView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

However, it tells me (when i am debugging it via Eclipse and my phone via USB) that:

*webpage not available*

What am i missing here? I know my phone has internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah.... i didn't have the permissions in my manifest file....

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```